# Prove that $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=f(x, \frac{dx}{dt})$ can be written in the form $\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{f(x,v)}{v}$:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Prove that $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=f(x, \frac{dx}{dt})$ can be written in the form:

$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{f(x,v)}{v}$ where $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All you need is the chain rule. $$\frac {dg}{dt} = \frac {dg}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ Now what should you put in for $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: When $\frac{dx}{dt}(t_0)\neq 0$ then you may perform a change of variables so that $x$ becomes the variable (by the inverse function theorem).